# Trouble writing data from python to postgreSQL with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to insert data from a python shell into a postgresql database using `psycopg2`. I'm trying to migrate the following database to a local postgreSQL file: http://www3.inegi.org.mx/sistemas/mapa/denue/default.aspx. Simplified example of workflow looks like this:

```
import psycopg2 
from psycopg2.extensions import ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT

DB_CONN_INEGI = 'host=localhost user=postgres password=password port=5432 dbname=inegi'

conn = psycopg2.connect(DB_CONN_INEGI)
conn.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

I then execute this command to insert some values into the table:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO denoue VALUES %s;" % tmp)
```

This executes just fine, but that when I check the record count with:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM denoue;')
```

This returns nothing (`None`). I can run the call above over and over again, but the result is always the same--no data seems to be getting added to the table.

Am I missing anything obvious? Apologies for lack of a quick working example--I can try to mock one up quickly that runs on local db if that would be useful here.

`tmp` looks like this:

```
"(40740, 'ZONA MILITAR', 'SECRETAR\\xc3\\x8dA DE LA DEFENSA NACIONAL', 931410, 'Impartici\\xc3\\xb3n de justicia y mantenimiento de la seguridad y el orden p\\xc3\\xbablico', '11 a 30 personas', 'CALLE', 'R\\xc3\\x8dO LERMA', 'CALLE', 'R\\xc3\\x8dO SENA', 'CALLE', 'R\\xc3\\x8dO \\xc3\\x89UFRATES', 'CALLE', 'R\\xc3\\x8dO LERMA', 100.0, 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'FRACCIONAMIENTO', 'COLINAS DEL R\\xc3\\x8dO', 'null', 'null', 'null', 20010.0, 1, 'AGUASCALIENTES', 1, 'AGUASCALIENTES', 1, 'Aguascalientes', '2013', 25, 'null', 'null', 'null', 'Fijo', 21.89341096, -102.32335734, 'DICIEMBRE 2014')"
```

Comment: Quick question: have you tried calling `conn.commit()` after the insert?

Comment: good idea. just tried it and that didn't solve the problem either, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cursor.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM denoue;')
```

This would actually execute a query and return `None`. To get the query results, you should use `fetchone()` method:

```
results_count = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

Comment: ah, that's it, thanks! As long as I have you here, can I ask how I would pull in all the records from the database into the python shell?

Comment: @Aaron sure, for example: `cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM denoue;')` and `print(cursor.fetchall())`.

Comment: ok, cool, this makes sense. i was looking for cursor.execute to actually return values. looks like the fetchone/fetchall commands are what get you there. thanks!